# Es6 class "this" in callback of requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I use the requestAnimationFrame inside a ES6 class such as

```
 class MyClass{...

     run(){
         requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
         //also tried requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate);
     }

     animate(){
        //how to get I back "this" here
     }
```

I cannot get back the reference to "this" in the callback of the requestAnimationFrame. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: run is a public method

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to bind the context either by using an arrow function:

```
 requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate());
```

or by binding the function to the context:

```
 requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
```

In newer JavaScript you could also use a class property containing an arrow function:

```
 class MyClass {
   run(){
     requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);         
   }

   animate = () => {
     //..      
   }
}
```

Comment: requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate); this doesn't work as noted in my code

Comment: @eric, right, you actually need to call the function

Comment: it's `() => this.animate()`

Comment: If you use the timestamp parameter sent to your callback function, then the bind syntax works nicely.

Comment: Is the `animate = () => { //.. }` safe now?

Comment: @gonnavis well it's specified, but the browser support is not yet there.

Answer (score 3):

[Jonas W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-w)'s answer is the way to go. You can also bind methods in constructor, like this:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.run = this.run.bind(this);
    this.animate = this.animate.bind(this);
  }
}
```